# how does the blocking work in priority ceiling protocol

Tags: real-time, semaphore, rtos, inversion

I dont understand why the priority of T3 is raised to P1, even though T1 requests the lock for resource a which is not used by either T2 or T3.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viR41.png)